# Create a UIAlertView once map pin is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, mapkit

I've been looking around for a solution to the custom callout on MKMapview and I don't want to add images and text to the left or right accessory view. I think I would rather create a UIAlertView that brings up all of the information that map pin that was selected.

I've gathered the lat and long on the map pin from JSON data and that JSON data also contains other info such as: phone number, website link, and so on.

How would I accomplish getting all of that information into a UIAlertView that is called upon pressing the map pin?

Here's some sample code:

```
self.result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

                         if(error == nil)

                             self.mapLocations = result;

                        NSLog(@"%@", [result allKeys]);

                         for (NSDictionary *location in self.mapLocations[@"merchants"]) {

                             for (NSDictionary *locations in location[@"branches"]) {
                                 NSLog(@"%@",locations);
                                 CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate =
                                 CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([locations[@"latitude"] doubleValue],
                                                            [locations[@"longitude"] doubleValue]);
                                 Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
                                 annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
                                 annotation.title = location[@"name"];
                                 annotation.subtitle = locations[@"street"];
                                 [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

and here is my MKAnnotationView Method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

        return nil;
    }
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annoPin"];
    MKAnnotationView *view = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annoView"];
    if(!view) {
        view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annoView"];
    }



    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(showDetails :) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    view.enabled = YES;
    view.canShowCallout = YES;
    return view;
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the UIAlertView after the disclosure button is pressed you should take out the line about assigning an action to the button and implement `– mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`. So long as your class is set to be the map's delegate then that function will be called and you can create your UIAlertView from there. On of the parameters to that function is the `annotationView` from which you can get the `MKAnnotation` and all the details should be attached to that.